# Cost for using Cloudwatch and lambda to start and stop instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using cloudwatch to trigger lambda to stop and start my instance everyday at particular time.I just wanted to know what will be the cost of using these instances. I tried searching but couldn't find anything

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/

I am using this documentation to achieve it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple monthly Calculator hosted on S3 and officially provided by AWS which can be used to check the price of different AWS services.

[SIMPLE MONTHLY CALCULATOR](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html)

You can use below links to calculate the price on the basis of number of events triggered in CloudWatch.

[Amazon CloudWatch pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/)

[AWS Pricing Calculator](https://calculator.aws/#/)

Comment: thanks for the reply.I want to know the charge for triggering an event using cloudwatch and I couldn't find it in the calculator.

Comment: Edited the answer to include few more helpful links.